# Composer won't install dependency

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I have created a composer package with this composer.json

```
{
    "name": "webiny/cache",
    "type": "library",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "jamm/memory": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Webiny\\Component\\Cache\\": ""
        }
    },
    "extras": {
        "branches": {
            "dev-master": "~0.9"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem with resolving `jamm/memory` package when I do a composer install on this file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "webiny/cache": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for webiny/cache dev-master -> satisfiable by webiny/cache[dev-master].
    - webiny/cache dev-master requires jamm/memory dev-master -> no matching package found.
```

When I just try to install the `jamm/memory` if works fine:

```
{
    "require": {
        "jamm/memory": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I have the `minimum-stability` flag set to `dev` in `webiny\cache`. I have also tried setting the release to `@dev` on `jamm/memory` dependency...didn't help.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it....
I added the `minimum-stability` flag to the composer.json file that I used to install the libraries...not just on the composer.json file that is used to define a package.