# Composer won't install private package dependencies

Tags: symfony, composer-php

First, there are some related posts which does not really fit to my problem.

- [Composer won't install dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583040/composer-wont-install-dependency)
- [Composer not installing local package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870095/composer-not-installing-local-package-dependencies)
- [Composer not installing dependencies of Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226203/composer-not-installing-dependencies-of-package)

and some more.

I have a Symfony Project which contains some private packages.
These are referenced by vcs:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@aaaaa.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@xxxxx.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@yyyyy.git"
    }
],
```

This works like expected. But, the private package yyyy referenced to another  private package (lets call it sub-yyyy), which is also referenced by type vcs in the package composer.json file.

If i run composer install it fails with the message:

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for yyyy -> yyyy].
>       - yyyy requires sub-yyyy ^1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>     https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>     details.
> - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

The private package (sub-yyyy) ist tagged by v1.0.0, and could be installed if its in the composer.json file of the main project.

**The composer.json of the main project (cutted out required):**

```
{
    "name": "main/project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@aaaaa.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@xxxxx.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@yyyyy.git"
        }
    ],
}
```

**The composer.json of the yyyy package:**

```
{
  "name": "yyyy",
  "type": "symfony-bundle",

  "require": {
    "sub-yyyy": "^1.0.0"
  },

  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@sub-yyyy.git"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
}
```

Any ideas to fix the problem when i install the `yyyy` package which references `sub-yyyy`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add repository entry to package `sub-yyyy` in your main project as dependencies entry is not transitive.

From [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories)

> Repositories are not resolved recursively. You can only add them to
>   your main composer.json. Repository declarations of dependencies'
>   composer.jsons are ignored.

Your `composer.json` of main project should look like

```
{
    "name": "main/project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@aaaaa.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@xxxxx.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@yyyyy.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@sub-yyyy.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ah, ok. thought there was a better solution for this. thank you

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out in the docs! Was having a hard time finding this answer. Also found an explanation why this is so that I found interesting: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-cant-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md